# Why frequentPushEnablementUpdates is not updating?

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit, activitykit, widgetliveactivity

At the moment, I am listening for any update in the `ActivityAuthorizationInfo,` but it never gets called.

```swift
for await frequentPushEnabled in self.activityAuthorizationInfo.frequentPushEnablementUpdates {
    // This never gets executed. Not even by toggling "More Frequent Updates."
}
```

1. How can I detect and test when the user turns off frequent push updates for the live activity?
2. Is it normal that the live activity gets dismissed when I turn off "More Frequent Updates"?

[image]